# Java StringBuilder Delete Last Occurance of Character Efficiently

Tags: java, performance, stringbuilder

What is the most efficient way to delete the last occurance of a `char` from a `StringBuilder`?

My current solution is `O(N)`, but I feel like this problem can be solved in constant time.

```
public StringBuilder deleteLastOccurance(StringBuilder builder, char c) {        
    int lastIndex = builder.lastIndexOf(String.valueOf(c));
    if (lastIndex != -1) {
        builder.deleteCharAt(lastIndex); // O(N)
    }
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: _but I feel like this problem can be solved in constant time_ Why do you have that feeling?

Comment: Also what is the complexity of `toString()`?

Comment: Notice that `lastIndexOf()` is also O(n).  You cannot do better than O(n).

Comment: This problem is naturally O(N) in computational cost. The computer needs to check each character starting from the end for the occurrence of your character. If you had an infinite number of cores and gave each core a constant length string, then the time it would take for each core to search its string would be constant, but aggregating the information would not be constant in time.

Comment: Hmm... turns out it looks like this is the best it can be. Looks like I should look to optimize elsewhere.

Comment: @budi you can optimize it by starting your search from the end of the string.

Comment: One small optimization you can make:  Replace `String.valueOf(c)` with just `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it will be an O(n) time no matter what. There is no other way to determine the last character without checking all the way to the end.

Even internal java API methods will have the same underlying implementation.

Comment: True it is best to search from the end of the string, however, Big O notation is based on a worse case scenario, indicating that if there was no letter in the sentence at all, it would still have to reach the beginning of the string(if we were starting from the end) to determine that there was actually no specific character at all.